# mongorestore: inspect archive dump file or validate --nsFrom parameter?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB server with database DB_A and DB_B. Using `mongodump` I create an archived dump of only database DB_A:

```
mongodump --uri "$MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING" --archive --gzip -db "DB_A"
```

After some time, I want to re-import this dump into another namespace using `mongorestore`, DB_C. Since I am very cautious, I want to test this command before using the test database "DB_B":

```
mongorestore --gzip --uri "$MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING" --nsFrom "DB_B.*" --nsTo "$DB_C.*" --drop --archive ./any-timestamp.tar.gz
```

I observed the following behaviour: Since the source namespace DB_B is not contained within the backup file, it will nevertheless restore the backup, completely ignoring both `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` parameters. So I completely reset the state of DB_A to the dumped state by mistake.

Is this the expected behaviour? How can I know, the dump file only contains a single database? Is there a way to explicitly validate the existence of the database named in the `--nsFrom` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

After this one too. In other RDBMS, there's a way to do something like RESTORE HEADERONLY on a DB dump and it will show you what's inside the dump file.